# My variable are hidden in my custom inspector (PropertyDrawer)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm going straight to the point! I'm using an enumerator to try to choose the variables I want to display, but for some reason the variables are not visible (half visible)

[An example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9yL2.png)

So, here is the part of the code that allows me to display and choose which variable to display :

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(QuestGoal))]
public class QuestGoal_PropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        SerializedProperty questType = property.FindPropertyRelative("questType");
        SerializedProperty item = property.FindPropertyRelative("item");
        SerializedProperty currentAmount = property.FindPropertyRelative("currentAmount");
        SerializedProperty totalAmount = property.FindPropertyRelative("totalAmount");
        SerializedProperty positionQuest = property.FindPropertyRelative("positionQuest");

        float lineHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, questType, GUIContent.none);


        switch (questType.intValue)
        {
            case (int)QuestType.CRAFTING:
                position = new Rect(position.x, position.y + lineHeight, position.width, position.height);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, item);
                break;
            case (int)QuestType.GATHERING:
                position = new Rect(position.x, position.y + lineHeight, position.width, position.height);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, currentAmount);
                position = new Rect(position.x, position.y + lineHeight * 2, position.width, position.height);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, totalAmount);
                break;
            case (int)QuestType.JOURNEY:
                position = new Rect(position.x, position.y + lineHeight, position.width, position.height);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, positionQuest);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
```

The switch allows me to choose my variables but there values ​​after the enumerator are still hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to implement:

```
        public override float GetPropertyHeight( SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label )
```

so the editor knows how much space to reserve for your property. Now you got the default height (probably EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight) and you need more so your property is clipped

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much, it was not really clear at first, but now I understand why it was doing that.

Comment: I also saw that in my code, there was a problem, I was giving the Rect -> `position.height`, when I had to give `EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(positionQuest)`. Which was causing me to only be able to interact with the enumerator and not the rest